# Any suggestions to increase width/height of .logo in Magento 2.0 Luma?

Tags: magento, magento2

any suggestions on what file to edit to increase width/height of .logo in Magento 2.0 Luma?

Answer (score 0):

you can configure the width and height of the logo in magento backend under store->configuration->General Design. check the Header block. you can able to see the width and height option for the logo.

Comment: thanks, i also found it at -  ./magento/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml